# Does any one know what is the problem here? The error is: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playershoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Action shootInput;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    }
        {
            shootInput?.Invoke();
        }
}
```

I watched a tutorial from youtube (I'm a new programmer to c#) and did exactly what I was told to but that happened.

Comment: Whenever you see "end of file expected" it is almost certainly a misplaced or missing `{` or `}`

Comment: That `}`  after `if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))` should not go there.

Answer (score 1):

Your Method is not properly closing the scope. Your if statement falls half outsite the method closing bracket so you have statements in places where they cant legally be placed

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    }
        { //here
            shootInput?.Invoke();
        } // here
```

it should be as below where the if statement is enclosed within the method definition

```
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            shootInput?.Invoke();
        }
    }
```